# @RequestMapping annotation ignoring POST, Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class RegisterController {

@RequestMapping("")
public String register() {
    return "register";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView registerUser(@RequestParam("emailsignup") String email,
                           @RequestParam("firstname") String firstName,
                           @RequestParam("lastname") String lastName,
                           @RequestParam("passwordsignup") String password) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    .... SQL code that inserts if it can
}
```

My register.jsp is just a regular form, I had this code working prior but it was mapping to "/" and was messing up my other mapping. When the POST form is clicked (if successful) I want it to return the user to /profile, if non successful to stay on /registration... how can I do this?

Comment: You should use `redirect:/profile` when it's successful and `redirect:/registration` when is not successful.

Comment: @HadiJ this is very useful, thank you - though it is not solving the problem that the method "registerUser" is being ignored, and when the submit button is clicked it returns to home page with no functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, HttpRedirectAttributes like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView registerUser(@RequestParam("emailsignup") String email,
                           @RequestParam("firstname") String firstName,
                           @RequestParam("lastname") String lastName,
                           @RequestParam("passwordsignup") String password,
                           RedirectAttributes redirect) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

               redirect.addFlashAttribute("emailsignup", emailsignup);
               redirect.addFlashAttribute("firstname", emailsignup);
               // Next 
               // Or redirect.addFlashAttribute("profile", profileObject)

               return modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/profile");
    }
```

Then in your jsp recover properties like this:

```
<label>${emailsignup} </label>
```

or

```
<label>${profileObject.emailsignup}</label>
```